# Stacking arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, stack

I have two arrays:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
B = np.array([2, 3, 4])
C = np.stack((A, B), axis=0)

print C.shape
(2, 3)
```

Shouldn't the shape be `(6,)` ?

Comment: No you stack over `axis=0`, so you create a 2d-array, where `C[0] == A`, and `C[1] == B`. You probably are looking for `np.hstack((A,B))`.

Comment: You mean, since I am stacking over `axis=0`, a new axis is created for `C`, which gives the shape of `(2, 3)` ?

Comment: Yes it creates a new axis. From the documentation[1], "Join a sequence of arrays along a new axis."
[1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

Comment: axis 0 is row direction. axis 1 is column direction *of the result* (!) not the arguments.

Comment: `stack` adds a new dimension. `np.concatenate` works on the existing one.

Comment: how about `np.hstack` and `np.vstack`, these too work on the existing ones.

Comment: In this case `vstack` does the same thing, turning the inputs into 2d arrays.  `hstack` is the same as `concatenate` on the last axis (here the only one).  It's a good idea to read their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `np.stack()` function you can specify which `axis` would you like to be considered the index axis. So as you can see you will never get a shape of `6`, only `(2,3)` or `(3,2)` for this example depending on what axis you chose.

See below:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
B = np.array([2, 3, 4])
arrays = [A, B]
```

With this code:

```
print(np.stack(arrays, axis=0))
```

you get this output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

with this code:

```
print(np.stack(arrays, axis=1))
```

you get this output:

```
[[1 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are stacking along axis 0. It is doing something like

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]]
```

If you want (6,) shape, you should use [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).