# reshaping numpy array/matrix

Tags: python, numpy

im trying to reshape the following numpy array.

from this:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[-1, -2, -3],
        [-2, -3, -4],
        [-3, -4, -5]]], dtype=int64)
```

to something like this:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [-1, -2, -3]],

       [[ 2,  3,  4],
        [-2, -3, -4]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [-3, -4, -5]]], dtype=int64)
```

Tried to use the `reshape` function, but that didnt work for me.

thanks

Comment: That's not a  reshape.  It's a transpose.  Try `arr.transpose(1,0,2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacking arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945669/stacking-arrays-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `np.stack` along axis `1`:

```
arr = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
                 [ 2,  3,  4],
                 [ 3,  4,  5]],

                [[-1, -2, -3],
                 [-2, -3, -4],
                 [-3, -4, -5]]])

np.stack(arr, 1)
```

results in

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [-1, -2, -3]],

       [[ 2,  3,  4],
        [-2, -3, -4]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [-3, -4, -5]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
               [ 2,  3,  4],
               [ 3,  4,  5]],
              [[-1, -2, -3],
               [-2, -3, -4],
               [-3, -4, -5]]], dtype=np.int64)
```

```
np.vstack(map(lambda x: [x], zip(*(x))))
```

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [-1, -2, -3]],
       [[ 2,  3,  4],
        [-2, -3, -4]],
       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [-3, -4, -5]]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use use the `numpy.reshape` function without any error.

Here's how:

```
a = array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
            [ 2,  3,  4],
            [ 3,  4,  5]],
           [[-1, -2, -3],
            [-2, -3, -4],
            [-3, -4, -5]]], dtype=int64)

a = a.reshape(3, 2, 3)
```

Here's what array 'a' will be converted into:

```
array([[[ 1  2  3]
        [ 2  3  4]]

       [[ 3  4  5]
        [-1 -2 -3]]

       [[-2 -3 -4]
        [-3 -4 -5]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a reshape problem.  It's transpose task - reordering the axes:

```
In [293]: arr.transpose(1,0,2)                                                          
Out[293]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [-1, -2, -3]],

       [[ 2,  3,  4],
        [-2, -3, -4]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [-3, -4, -5]]])
```

`stack` works by iterating on the first dimension, and concatenating on a new middle axis.  `transpose` just makes a `view` so will be faster.